# How to simplify and condense my encryption code?

Tags: performance, python-3.x

I have recently finished a mimi project of mine to create a encryptor, right now it only works for text, I was just wondering how i could make it read more simply and to condense the amount of code as right now it takes 208 lines.

Code:

```
import os
import os.path
import time
import ctypes
import hashlib as h
import tkinter.messagebox as box
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
    
Word, Words, EncryptedWord, count, Number, sep, Condition, NumberOfNormal, ListNumber, DecryptedWord = ([], [], [], 0, 0, ", ", True, 0, 0, [])
class IncorrectPassword(Exception):
    pass


class IncorrectUsername(Exception):
    pass


class IncorrectCommand(Exception):
    pass


def DataCollection(event = None):
    global Entered_username, Entered_password
    Entered_username = Username_entry.get()
    Entered_password = Password_entry.get()
    Details()

    
def Registering():
    global Username_entry, Password_entry, Enter_Username, Enter_Password, Entry_button
    New_or_Old.destroy()
    New.destroy()
    Old.destroy()
    U_and_P = open(r"C:\Users\tommy\Documents\Python\Username and password.txt", "w")
    Enter_Username = Label(window, text = "Enter a username: ")
    Enter_Username.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    Enter_Password = Label(window, text = "Enter a password: ")
    Enter_Password.place(x = 0, y = 27)
    Username_entry = Entry(window)
    Username_entry.place(x = 150, y = 0)
    Password_entry = Entry(window, show = "*")
    Password_entry.place(x = 150, y = 30)
    Entry_button = Button(window, text = "Enter", command = DataCollection)
    Entry_button.place(x = 160, y = 60)
    Password_entry.bind("<Return>", DataCollection)


def Details(event = None):
    global Username_entry, Password_entry, Enter_Username, Enter_Password, Entry_button
    Username = Username_entry.get()
    Password = Password_entry.get()
    Password = h.md5(Password.encode()).hexdigest()
    U_and_P = open(r"C:\Users\tommy\Documents\Python\Username and password.txt", "w")
    U_and_P.write("Username: " + Username + "\n")
    U_and_P.write("Password: " + Password)
    U_and_P.close()
    Done()
def Login():
    global Entered_username_entry, Entered_password_entry, Entered_username_label, Entered_password_label, Entered_entry_button, Entered_password, Username, Password
    New_or_Old.destroy()
    New.destroy()
    Old.destroy()
    U_and_P = open(r"C:\Users\tommy\Documents\Python\Username and password.txt", "r")
    Extraction = U_and_P.readlines()
    Username = Extraction[0].strip("ï»¿").strip("\n")
    Password = Extraction[1]
    Username = Username[10: ]
    Password = Password[10: ]
    Entered_username_label = Label(window, text = "Enter your username: ")
    Entered_username_label.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    Entered_password_label = Label(window, text = "Enter your password: ")
    Entered_password_label.place(x = 0, y = 27)
    Entered_username_entry = Entry(window)
    Entered_username_entry.place(x = 150, y = 0)
    Entered_password_entry = Entry(window, show = "*")
    Entered_password_entry.place(x = 150, y = 30)
    Entered_entry_button = Button(window, text = "Enter", command = Check)
    Entered_entry_button.place(x = 160, y = 60)
    Entered_username_entry.bind("<Return>", Check)
    Entered_password_entry.bind("<Return>", Check)

def Check(event = None):
    global Entered_username_entry, Entered_password_entry, Entered_username_label, Entered_password_label, Entered_entry_button, Entered_username, Entered_password, Username, Password
    Entered_username = Entered_username_entry.get()
    Entered_password = Entered_password_entry.get()
    Hashed_password = h.md5(Entered_password.encode()).hexdigest()
    if Username == Entered_username:
        if Password == Hashed_password:
            Done()
        else:
            raise IncorrectPassword
    else:
        raise IncorrectUsername
def Done():
    global TotalChar
    UserList, PassList, TotalUser, TotalPass = [], [], 1, 1
    for i in range(len(Entered_username)):
        User = ord(Entered_username[i])
        UserList.append(User)
    for i in range(len(Entered_password)):
        Pass = ord(Entered_password[i])
        PassList.append(Pass)
    for i in range(len(Entered_username)):
        TotalUser = int(UserList[i] * TotalUser)
    for i in range(len(Entered_password)):
        TotalPass = int(PassList[i] * TotalPass)
    TotalChar = int(TotalUser * TotalPass)
    EncryptOrDecrypt()

    
def Encryption():
    EncryptOrDecryptWin.destroy()
    ewdfa = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    Check = list(ewdfa)
    eodf = open(ewdfa, "r+").read()
    encrypt = eodf.swapcase()
    eone = encrypt[2: ] + encrypt[: 2]
    for i in eone:
        etwo = chr(ord(i) + 5)
        Words.append(etwo)
        etwo = "".join(Words)
    for g in range(len(etwo)):
        global EncryptedWord, Number
        ethree = ord(Words[Number])
        ethree = (ethree * 20) + 59
        efour = int(ethree * TotalChar)
        efive = "{0:b}".format(efour)
        EncryptedWord.append(efive)
        Number = Number + 1
    esix = ", ".join(str(x) for x in EncryptedWord)
    os.remove(ewdfa)
    NewFile = open(ewdfa, "w")
    NewFile.write(esix)
    NewFile.close()
    window.destroy()
    quit()

    
def Decryption():
    EncryptOrDecryptWin.destroy()
    dwdfa = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    global Condition, ListNumber, NumberOfNormal
    Check = list(dwdfa)
    dodf = open(dwdfa, "r+").read()
    while Condition:
        try:
            ListString = dodf.split(sep, ListNumber)[ListNumber]
            NumberOfNormal = NumberOfNormal + 1
            ListNumber = ListNumber + 1
        except IndexError:
            break
    ListNumber = 0
    for v in range(NumberOfNormal):
        Decrypted = dodf.split(sep, NumberOfNormal)[ListNumber]
        ListNumber = ListNumber + 1
        Decrypted = int(Decrypted, 2)
        Decrypted = int(Decrypted / TotalChar)
        Decrypted = (Decrypted - 59) / 20
        Decrypted = int(Decrypted)
        DecryptedWord.append(chr(Decrypted))
    dodf = "".join(DecryptedWord)
    a = len(DecryptedWord)
    time.sleep(1)
    dfirst = dodf[a - 2] + dodf[a - 1] + dodf[: a - 2]
    for i in dfirst:
        dsecond = chr(ord(i) - 5)
        Word.append(dsecond)
        dsecond = "".join(Word)
    dsecond = dsecond.swapcase()
    os.remove(dwdfa)
    new = open(dwdfa, "w")
    new.write(dsecond)
    new.close()
    window.destroy()
    quit()

    
def EncryptOrDecrypt():
    global EncryptOrDecryptWin
    EncryptOrDecryptWin = Toplevel(window)
    window.withdraw()
    EncryptOrDecryptWin.title("Encryption or Decryption.")
    EncryptOrDecryptWin.geometry("360x150")
    EncryptOrDecryptFrame = Frame()
    EncryptOrDecryptFrame.place()
    EncryptOrDecryptLabel = Label(
    EncryptOrDecryptWin, text = "Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt?")
    EncryptOrDecryptLabel.place(x = 65, y = 0)
    Encrypt = Button(EncryptOrDecryptWin, text = "Encrypt", command = Encryption)
    Decrypt = Button(EncryptOrDecryptWin, text = "Decrypt", command = Decryption)
    Encrypt.place(x = 100, y = 30)
    Decrypt.place(x = 200, y = 30)


window = Tk()
window.title("Login frame")
window.geometry("350x150")
Loginframe = Frame()
Loginframe.place()
New_or_Old = Label(window, text = "Are you registering or are you loging in?")
New_or_Old.place(x = 43, y = 0)
New = Button(window, text = "Registering", command = Registering)
New.place(x = 100, y = 30)
Old = Button(window, text = "Login", command = Login)
Old.place(x = 195, y = 30)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: One detail - when you have non-obvious statements like `.strip("ï»¿")` - I'd put a comment explaining what this means. It's removing the Unicode byte order mark, or something like that, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, however this isn't a piece of code that I would make public as it just satiated my desire to try to create a encryption program. What I am try to do is make it more concise and hopefully shortern down the amount of code.

Comment: I just changed my title and description to better display my intentions for this code.

Comment: Initializing 10 variables on a single line might condense code but it certainly does not simplify it.

Comment: Please don't modify the code of the question after you have received answers.  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of code repetition between these two functions that could be removed by a `build_standard_ui` function called once in both functions. Of course this function will have as arguments the functions that should run when the buttons are clicked to suit it to the different situations.

```
def Registering():
    global Username_entry, Password_entry, Enter_Username, Enter_Password, Entry_button
    New_or_Old.destroy()
    New.destroy()
    Old.destroy()
    U_and_P = open(r"C:\Users\tommy\Documents\Python\Username and password.txt", "w")
    Enter_Username = Label(window, text = "Enter a username: ")
    Enter_Username.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    Enter_Password = Label(window, text = "Enter a password: ")
    Enter_Password.place(x = 0, y = 27)
    Username_entry = Entry(window)
    Username_entry.place(x = 150, y = 0)
    Password_entry = Entry(window, show = "*")
    Password_entry.place(x = 150, y = 30)
    Entry_button = Button(window, text = "Enter", command = DataCollection)
    Entry_button.place(x = 160, y = 60)
    Password_entry.bind("<Return>", DataCollection)

def Login():
    global Entered_username_entry, Entered_password_entry, Entered_username_label, Entered_password_label, Entered_entry_button, Entered_password, Username, Password
    New_or_Old.destroy()
    New.destroy()
    Old.destroy()
    U_and_P = open(r"C:\Users\tommy\Documents\Python\Username and password.txt", "r")
    Extraction = U_and_P.readlines()
    Username = Extraction[0].strip("ï»¿").strip("\n")
    Password = Extraction[1]
    Username = Username[10: ]
    Password = Password[10: ]
    Entered_username_label = Label(window, text = "Enter your username: ")
    Entered_username_label.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    Entered_password_label = Label(window, text = "Enter your password: ")
    Entered_password_label.place(x = 0, y = 27)
    Entered_username_entry = Entry(window)
    Entered_username_entry.place(x = 150, y = 0)
    Entered_password_entry = Entry(window, show = "*")
    Entered_password_entry.place(x = 150, y = 30)
    Entered_entry_button = Button(window, text = "Enter", command = Check)
    Entered_entry_button.place(x = 160, y = 60)
    Entered_username_entry.bind("<Return>", Check)
    Entered_password_entry.bind("<Return>", Check)
```

---

Miscellaneous improvements:

Avoid hardcoding the path     `U_and_P = open(r"C:\Users\tommy\Documents\Python\Username and password.txt", "w")`
inside the program but put it in a constant at the start to change it easier if/when needed.

---

Use the standard `python_naming_convention` of snake case.

---

Avoid cutting the data:

```
Username = Username[10: ]
Password = Password[10: ]
```

without telling the user.